How can I show that $\bigcap\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} [{k \over n}, {k+1 \over n}]^2=\{(x,x):x\in [0,1]\}$
Let $X=[0,1]$ given  $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$. $\Delta_n = \bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[{k \over n}, {k+1 \over n} \right]^2$?
How can I show that $\Delta=\cap\Delta_n$? It's ok showing $\Delta\subset\cap\Delta_n$ because every $\Delta_n$ contains $\Delta$
but I don't know how to do the opposite?

As an idea of proof, try to show two implications: $a \in \Delta \Rightarrow a \in \cap \Delta_n$ and vice versa.

One direction is immediate. For the other show that any off diagonal element is excluded by some $n$. Drawing a picture might help.

It might help indeed to draw your rectangles. Which point in the rectangle is the furthest away from the diagonal? What is the distance in terms of $n$?

I use $\langle a,b\rangle$; $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$; to denote the point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with first coordinate $a$, second coordinate $b$, I do this to not overload the notation $(a,b)$, which may be taken to mean $\{x \in \mathbb{R}; \  a < x<b\}$.
This is a SKETCH. Make sure you are able to follow.
Clearly each $\Delta_n$ is a subset of $[0,1]^2$ to start. So it remains to show that, given both $0 \le a,b \le 1$, point $\langle a,b \rangle$ is in all the $\Delta_n$s; $n \in \mathbb{N}$; iff the equation $a=b$ is satisfied.
We show that "if" direction, that $\langle a,a \rangle$ is in $\Delta_n$ for all $a \in [0,1]$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For each such $a \in [0,1]$ and for each such $n$, there is a nonnegative integer $k \le n$ such that $a$ is in $[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]$, and thus $\langle a,a \rangle$ is in $[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}]^2 \subseteq \Delta_n$. So indeed, $\langle a,a \rangle$ is in $\Delta_n$ for all $a \in [0,1]$ and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and so the "if" direction is satisfied.
Now it remains to show the "only if", that there is a $\Delta_n$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is not in $\Delta_n$ iff the relation $a \not = b$ is true. HINT:
Let $n$ be any positive integer such that $\frac{1}{n} < |a-b|$. Then
there cannot exist a $k$ such that both relations $a \in [\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}]$ and $b \in [\frac{k}{n}, \frac{k+1}{n}]$ are satisfied simultaneously. Thus, $\langle a,b\rangle$ cannot be in $\Delta_n$ for that particular $n$ at least. You can take it from here.

Thanks ,  one of very few that has read my problem and didn't downvote it.
